# Is there a way to clean the null data of 2 different CSVs at once?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My aim with this is to be able to create one dataframe that will have data from the 2 CSVs in it and also be able to address the rows with null values.

I have 2 [CSVs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17U1lLj43he_DYbiuvD_wLH2xPgFJ6c1O-k6dScVCAHc/edit?usp=sharing)(link to the google sheet), sheet one is nifty, sheet 2 is nsebank. When I have to clean the sheets individually, I either use dropna or replace null values with say a mean. Mentioned the code below.

But nifty sheet has 35 null values while nsebank has 305 null values. Because the null values are different, I wanted to know if there is a way I can read both CSVs in the same dataframe and act upon the null values. For instance, because there are a lot more null values in the nsebank sheet, if I just read it into the same dataframe as nifty sheet and dropna, a lot of the nifty sheet data for those dates will be gone.

For e.g. if I am to pull data out of AV or from any other data provider, cleaning up data for individual stocks is going to be tedious and slow.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bnf = pd.read_csv('nsebank.csv', index_col=0)
newbnf = bnf.dropna()

newbnf['Daily Returns'] = newbnf['Adj Close'].pct_change()
```

Comment: Can you please be a little more clear with your query? Not able to understand what you want to get

Comment: If you download the CSVs from the link I have shared, you will see two sheets. nifty and nsebank. nifty sheet has 35 null rows and nsebank sheet has 305 null rows. I want to be able to read both the sheets into the same dataframe and perform my analysis by dropping rows with null value from the sheets, however, If I use the dropna() method, then because nse bank sheet has 305 null rows, I will lose valuable data even from the nifty sheet. Note that this is a timeseries data.

Comment: What is your expected output dataset? If a common date coordinate is used for multiple stocks, and some nulls occur only for one stock,  then there is simply no way to drop all rows containing nulls without losing data. You either lose those data, or use a null-tolerating data processing method...

Comment: Thanks Bill, I will probably check for some way to fill in the missing data.

Answer (score 0):

I simply concatenated the two excel sheets and did dropna(). See, if that works for you.

```
df_nifty = pd.read_excel('Indexdata.xlsx', sheet_name= 'nifty')
df_bnf = pd.read_excel('Indexdata.xlsx', sheet_name= 'bnf')
df = pd.concat([df_nifty, df_bnf])
df.dropna(inplace = True)
```

Comment: No, that doesn't solve the purpose, because it is time series data. I need lets say the 'Adj Close' column of nifty and nse bank side by side. For e.g. what price did bnf & nifty close at on 17/9/2007. So date becomes the index. In your sheet, calculate how many rows the nsebank sheet is left with after you dropna vs the rows nifty sheet is left with. It will be 3038 and 3308 respectively. Both need to have same number of rows.

Comment: Okay. Got it! Well in that case I would suggest you to impute the missing values in the datasets. That's what we do in time series datasets.

Comment: Thanks Vatsal, will try this.